# How can I send data to the server via HTML?

Tags: html

I just started with Html and I want to send some input info collected from the front end to my server. The source I’m learning from is very blunt on this point. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use an HTML form.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

```
<form action="https://url.goes.here" method="post">
  <label for="full-name">Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="full-name" name="full-name" placeholder="Your Full Name" required autocomplete="name" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How does the data look like when it gets received in the server?

Comment: That will depend on the `type` attribute of the `input` elements and what your user submits. I recommend going over the MDN link I posted to see some different examples and trying them out on your machine.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="https://<yourwebsitedomain>/login_form" method="post">
  <label for="username">Your Username</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Type your username" required />
  <label for="email">Type your email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Type your email" required />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

At the server side the parameters will be like a hash with keys as the name attribute of the input field and the value will be the value filled by the user. Lets say user fills the username as "username" and email as "youremail@gmail.com", then the hash will be like { 'username' => 'username', 'email' => 'youremail@gmail.com' }
The way that you extract and use these parameters/hash will depend on the language that you are using for the back end.